# Can you broadcast a segwit transaction using a non segwit node?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

If non segwit nodes view segwit transactions as anyone can spend ,why can't you broadcast a segwit transaction using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segwit was designed in such a way that segwit transactions, after removing the witness, are **valid** but **non-standard** to old nodes.

This guarantees that old nodes won't reject such transactions when they're seen in blocks, but still won't be relayed or mined by old software.

Comment: Does this apply to all SegWit transactions, including P2SH-nested types?

Comment: @ChrisChen Indeed. All segwit spends violate the "clean stack" standardness rule implemented by most pre-segwit Bitcoin Core versions.